# Notification Center not calling when bridging from Unity to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unity-game-engine, nsnotificationcenter

We currently have a Unity (C#-based) application that requires us to detect volume button presses in iOS. We currently bridge to native iOS code via a Objective-C++ bridge and that bridge interfaces with our Swift code.

My idea was to subscribe to the exposed `AVSystemController` API to tell us every time the volume changed, but it doesn't seem to be triggering when the associated Notification is fired. We have it set up like so:

VolumeDetector.mm

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import "unityswift-Swift.h"

@interface VolumeDetectorDelegateHandler: NSObject<VolumeDetectorDelegate>

@end

@implementation VolumeDetectorDelegateHandler

- (void)volumeDidChange {
    UnitySendMessage("UIManager", "TakePicPressed", "Volume Changed");
}

@end

extern "C" {
    void subscribeToVolumeButtons() {
        VolumeDetector *detector = [VolumeDetector new];
        VolumeDetectorDelegateHandler *handler = [VolumeDetectorDelegateHandler new];
        detector.delegate = handler;
        MPVolumeView *mpVolumeview = [MPVolumeView new];
        [mpVolumeview setShowsVolumeSlider:NO];
        detector.volumeView = mpVolumeview;
        [detector subscribeToVolumeButtons];
    }
}
```

VolumeDetector.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

@objc public protocol VolumeDetectorDelegate {
    func volumeDidChange()
}

public class VolumeDetector: NSObject {
    @objc public var delegate: VolumeDetectorDelegate?
    @objc public var volumeView: MPVolumeView?

    @objc func subscribeToVolumeButtons() {
        print("Subscribing to volume buttons");

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
                                            selector: #selector(volumeChanged(notification:)),
                                            name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"),
                                            object: nil)
    }

    @objc func volumeChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("Volume changed")
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            if let volumeChangeType = userInfo["AVSystemController_AudioVolumeChangeReasonNotificationParameter"] as? String {
                if volumeChangeType == "ExplicitVolumeChange" {
                    print("Explicit volume changed")
                    delegate?.volumeDidChange()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This protocol-orientated design works well for callbacks in other use cases, but in this case it seems that `volumeChanged` is not being called.

I have tested this exact code in a native Xcode project and it works..so not worried there's an issue with 'AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification'.

**Solution:**

As Rob Napier pointed out, I had to keep a strong reference to the delegate handler so that the observer would hang around. Here is the updated, working code:

VolumeDetector.mm

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import "unityswift-Swift.h"

@interface VolumeDetectorDelegateHandler: NSObject<VolumeDetectorDelegate>
@property (strong, retain) VolumeDetector *detector;
@property (strong, retain) MPVolumeView *volumeView;
@end

static VolumeDetectorDelegateHandler *handler;

@implementation VolumeDetectorDelegateHandler

- (void) subscribeToVolButtons {
    _detector = [VolumeDetector new];
    _detector.delegate = handler;
    [_detector subscribeToVolumeButtons];
}

-(void)volumeDidChange {
    UnitySendMessage("UIManager", "TakePicPressed", "Volume Changed");
}

@end

extern "C" {
    void subscribeToVolumeButtons() {
        handler = [VolumeDetectorDelegateHandler new];
        [handler subscribeToVolButtons];
    }
}
```

VolumeDetector.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

@objc public protocol VolumeDetectorDelegate {
    func volumeDidChange()
}

public class VolumeDetector: NSObject {
    @objc public var delegate: VolumeDetectorDelegate?

    @objc func subscribeToVolumeButtons() {
        if let vc = UnityGetGLViewController() {
            let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect(x:-100, y:0, width:0, height:0))
            volumeView.showsRouteButton = false
            vc.view.addSubview(volumeView);

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                    selector: #selector(volumeChanged(notification:)),
                                                    name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"),
                                                    object: nil)
        }
    }

    @objc func volumeChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            if let volumeChangeType = userInfo["AVSystemController_AudioVolumeChangeReasonNotificationParameter"] as? String {
                if volumeChangeType == "ExplicitVolumeChange" {
                    delegate?.volumeDidChange()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a detector in `subscribeToVolumeButtons()`, it subscribes to the notification, and then you immediately throw away the detector. At that point, you should expect it to automatically unsubscribe from the notification. If you want the detector to stay around and keep functioning, you're going to need something that holds a strong reference to it.

If you add a `deinit` to `VolumeDetector`, I expect that it will get fired shortly after `subscribeToVolumeButtons()` returns.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed was the problem. I have updated my question to include the solution.